# How to avoid being downvoted for a genuine, well researched question?

Tags: discussion

**I am new to Stack Overflow**. I am also new to PHP and MySQL. I have received downvotes and upvotes for several questions that I have asked on Stack Overflow on PHP and MySQL. I am really thankful to the answers provided by experts on this site since I have always got an answer to almost every question that I have posted so far, and I have learnt a lot.

But what is agonizing for me is that I have received **downvotes** even for those questions which were well researched, properly formatted, grammatically correct (at least to the best of my ability) and genuine. I have corroborated my questions with facts including snapshots of the problems that I have faced and the code where the problem occurs. Now, after receiving downvotes for some of my questions, I keep getting a warning that I am in the risk of being blocked for asking any further questions.

**I have checked out the links on this site which provides information on how to ask good questions**. I have adhered to all the points mentioned in these articles.

If I don't ask questions about the problems that I face, I am not going to learn anymore. At the same time, if I keep getting downvotes for some of my questions, I run a risk of being blocked from asking any further questions.
As a beginner in PHP and MySQL, I know I am going to have a lot of problems.

**What more can I do to avoid being downvoted?**

Comment: *"...well researched,..."* Read the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593) in this post: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Answer (score 15):

It's great that you have paid attention to the resources available, and started a dialogue here. With that attitude, you'll be evolving into a good dev, no matter what happens to your SO account.

From a *very* cursory review of your questions, a scattershot, incomplete list of things you can do:

- **Asking a question on Stack Overflow is literally the last thing you should do.** Meaning: try *every other resource* first, especially Google. Google your intended question title, and variations of it. That's a rule that applies to *everyone*, not only new users. Most questions you will have, have already been asked. If you ask a duplicate question, it doesn't matter whether it's well worded - it's still a duplicate question. You ask very specific, well-laid-out questions, but with some of them I can't help but think there's already good answers out there - if not in a Stack Overflow question, then in a tutorial.
- **Remember Stack Overflow is not a replacement for study, a course, a book, or at least a tutorial. Not every problem you will face while learning to code will have a place on Stack Overflow.** Some conceptual questions about basic principles like [your one about success messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001544/how-can-i-print-a-success-message-for-insert-update-or-delete) are perfectly valid questions in themselves, but they don't generally do well on SO because it is very focused on specific technical problems rather than broader concepts. Look for resources that help you get into the broader concepts first.

  A personal example: I'm learning Swift on iOS at the moment, and I've started taking a couple of video courses and tutorials to learn the basic broad concepts  (where do you put your files, how do you exchange data between views, etc.) because I know it's very basic stuff and asking about them on Stack Overflow doesn't really work.
- **Always capitalize "I"**, especially in question titles. E.g. `How can i print a success message for insert,update or delete?` Lowercase "i"'s are often an indicator of low quality questions and some people may vote accordingly without checking out the question in detail.
- **Punctuation.** There's no space before a period, and one space after. Unlike in French, English has no spaces before question marks and exclamation points.

  > This is a line of text where the punctuation is wrong.What an outrage !
  >
  > This is a line of text where the punctuation is correct. [Strunk & White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) are happy to see it!

Comment: so _that's_ where the badge name comes from.....